# android studio and java problem with code

Tags: java, android

I created a project to display videos when i refer to (raw) file by R. However, I can't find it even though this file exist in res:

[image]

Comment: Whats the file name? Under the resources directory, everything has to be lowercase and _ otherwise they don't get picked up.

Comment: Try clean/rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you place the raw resource file in the project, you could click **File-sync with File System** menu, or the shortcut `ctrl + alt + Y` .

you could check if it successful via below line:

```
final int resID = R.raw.test;
```

**Edited:** 
    If above operations finished successfully, you will see fig as below:
[image]

You could test to add a simple text file firstly.

Comment: Thank you very much for this help it works
but Do I need to repeat this every project؟